# Error when render component with custom button to login with Google API

Tags: vue.js, google-api, vue-component, google-oauth

I have created a custom button component in vue.js for some actions related to user account interactions. In it I can receive a property that define it as a custom Google button as defined in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button.

But, if I use mounted component property to activate it, this error is returned: **"Uncaught RefereceError: auth2 is not defined**.

I put `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>` in *index.html* file, so **gapi** object and his **load** method works, but the *'auth2'* is not received.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    console.log('gapi load!');
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({ // error here
      client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    });
    this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('google-signin'));
  });
```

If I use this method in *index.html* works propertly, but I want mantain it on the specifc component.

Somebody know a maner to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **Uncaught RefereceError: auth2 is not defined** throw because of you are trying to assign `auth2` before you declare it:

```js
let auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({ // use let to declare it
  client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
});
```

And

```js
this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('google-signin'));
```

may cause you another error if you are define `attachSignin` as a Vue method then you should use arrow function (at parent) but if you define it in the same scope then just remove `this`.

Another approach:

```html
<div>
  <div class="button" ref="button">
    <img class="icon" src="/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png">
    <span>Google</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    // This will prevent unnecessary load if we already loaded or we are loading it.
    if (!window.gapiPromise) {
      window.gapiPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        let script = document.createElement("script");
        script.addEventListener("load", () => {
          resolve(window.gapi);
        });
        script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      });
    }

    window.gapiPromise.then(gapi => {
      gapi.load("auth2", () => {
        let auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin"
        });
        auth2.attachClickHandler(this.$refs.button, {});
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-water-gt1n6).

Comment: Thanks @user-28. The code is in the question, but I don't refer to the Google script in it, as in your example. I think my approach is really wrong and I will test it with the material from your answer. I will return with the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it I though that code only use in index.html.  I update my answer, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be your error:

> All lifecycle hooks automatically have their this context bound to the instance, so that you can access data, computed properties, and methods. This means you should not use an arrow function to define a lifecycle method (e.g. created: () => this.fetchTodos()). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and this.fetchTodos will be undefined.

This is explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks). So you should access to your **variable** without using variable instead of **this.variable**. I hope this could help